# Code hidden in answer preview

Tags: bug

I run into some weird problem. When i tried to edit question [preg_match issues using php variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868125/preg-match-issues-using-php-variable)

> I've edited code which i paste below:
>
> 1. change `/d` to `\d`
> 2. there is no need to use `.*`
> 3. if your string is defined by user (or may contains some characters (e.g: `/` or `*` or `...`)) this may cause problem on your match.

And even here i can't see code. I attach screenshot so it can be little clearer:

> [image]

**Is it a bug?**

Comment: Why is your screenshot of your meta post? Is the issue on stackoverflow or not?

Comment: Well, the issue is that i have some code in my answer (as you can see, it's on meta *and* on stackoverflow), but it's somehow hidden. In this question i pasted everything that's on screenshot. Can you see that PHP part? Me neither :)

Answer (score 4):

After some investigating it seems that it won't render unless:

- There's some "filler" between the text and code block, like an empty comment `<!-- -->`
- There's five spaces instead of four after the blockquote symbol `>`

Whether or not this is a bug, I'd say it's more trouble than it's worth. Just format code the proper vetted ways:

- Don't blockquote it, unless you're actually quoting something
- Indent by 4 spaces, or use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
- Use `<pre><code>` and escape if necessary

A similar issue happens with code followed by bulleted lists, where you have to add filler for it to render properly. Example:

- without comment

  ## include
- with comment

```
#include <iostream>
```